# Application throws exception when trying to download file second time

Tags: c#

In my WPF application, I am showing a list of URLs against file names and clicking on the link will download the file using this code:

```
private void Content_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/octet-stream");
            var file = link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri.Split('/');
            client.DownloadFile(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri, file[file.Count() - 1]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

---

The issue is first time download goes through where as second time following error is thrown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>   Additional information: ContentType string is not valid. Expected format is type/subtype.

Can you help?

Comment: If you are catching the exception, how can it be unhandled? Or did you add the catch afterwards?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the content-type of your request to `octet-stream`? Did you mean to set the accept header?

Answer (score 0):

If exception is unhandled even if you use catch in method, try to add     Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource under catch block.